# create custom django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler using googleapp engine sendmail api

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, sendmail

hi i'am trying to override django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler class so as to send mails using google app engine mail api with

```
from google.appengine.api import mail

from django.utils.log import AdminEmailHandler

class CustomEmailHandler(AdminEmailHandler):
   def send_mail(self, subject, message, *args, **kwargs):
        logging.critical('inside sendmail')
        mailer = mail.EmailMessage(sender="xyz@gmail.com",
                                   subject=subject)
        mailer.to = "xyz@gmail.com"
        mailer.body = """Please let us know if you have any questions.
        The example.com Team    """
        mailer.send()
```

and logging config as per django docs is :

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'myapp.email_handler.CustomEmailHandler',
        },

    },

    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins' ],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

the admin tuple is given as

```
ADMINS=(('xyz','xyz@gmail.com'),)
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution i wasn't raising a Exception in the view call. I was  returning a response status of 500 
`return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)`

but that wasn't enough on adding `raise Exception('mesg')` to the view call the code works fine and mail is triggered